# How to configure a new subdomain for a wildcard certificate?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, hostname

We have wildcard certificate installed in our production environment. One of our client wants his name to appear in the URL (e.g. `companyname.example.com`). How we should facilitate this?

Do we need to make any entries for this in DNS? If yes can you please let me know about it?

I need to set this up before Fridat PST, any help in this is highly appriciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need to configure `companyname.example.com` in DNS in addition to making sure your webserver knows what to do with `companyname.example.com` (there are lots of posts about VirtualHosts in apache, which is probably what you need if using apache).

Good luck,

--jed

Comment: yep, the wildcard cert requires a valid domain name for the cert to validate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For any domain name to be located on the internet, it needs to have a DNS record. So yes, you need to set this up in the DNS.

How you want to go about this depends on your specific setup. If you want to share the same IP address for the subdomain as the primary domain, you need to create a `CNAME` record called `companyname`, pointing to `example.com`.

If it's going to be on its own IP address (which is most likely), you will need to create an `A` record, pointing to the IP address of the server (e.g. `companyname` points to `xx.xx.xx.xx`).

From that point, you need to set up a new website (IIS) or a virtualhost (Apache) to serve the content and the certificate. More information is required. You may also need a dedicated IP address just for this. Your milage may vary, but there's a LOT of instructions on how to do this already on ServerFault.